# 404 Redirect Error with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wampserver

I'm running a website on a local server (using WAMP Server) and I'm trying to test to see if my 404 page would work, but when I try to navigate to a nonexistent page, I get an error that says:

```
The requested URL /dsf/sdkmf was not found on this server. 
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an 
ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

My 404 page is in the root folder with all my other pages and my .htaccess Error Document handle is listed as:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I don't know why it's throwing me this error much less how to fix it, does it have something to do with my WAMPServer configuration?

Comment: Sounds strange... try to raise the LogLevel in the main Apache conf file (eg. `LogLevel Debug`), this may help to track what page the server is trying to fetch (without finding it).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I figured out how to solve it on my own - apparently you have to use the direct path to the file - even if it's in the root directory of the site itself!